# Error when using SOAP in CodeIgniter: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated

Tags: php, codeigniter, soap

I have an application written in codeigniter which uses SOAP to get data and output it to the page.
Before using SOAP in my project,i did a couple of test in plain php and it worked perfectly.
This is the actual code that i used both in codeigniter and in plain php:

```
require_once("SOAP/Client.php");

$api_key='89c2ed9c14dfaff162ec516e37d3055d'; // API Key received from Nexus Electronics
$vehicles=array('B116KAI-MIHAI BALOI');

$sw=new SOAP_WSDL('http://gpstracking.ro/en/api.php?wsdl',array('timeout'=>0));
$proxy=$sw->getProxy();

$erg=$proxy->getVisitedHotspots($api_key,$vehicles,'2015-06-28','2015-06-29 21:59:59 GMT');

echo '<table border="2">';
echo '<th>hotspotName</th>';
echo '<th>stopTimeISO8601</th>';
echo '<th>stationaryTimeSec</th>';
echo '<th>odometerKM</th>';

foreach($erg->response[0]->visitedHotspots as $i){
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>'.$i->hotspotName.'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$i->stopTimeISO8601.'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$i->stationaryTimeSec.'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$i->odometerKM.'</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

This exact code in codeigniter produces 11 errors,although the table is properly displayed and the code works fine.

The errors say:

> 'Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated' or ' Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated' or 'Redefining already defined constructor for class Net_URL' or ' Non-static method PEAR::getStaticProperty() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context' or'Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context' or 'Non-static method SOAP_Transport::getTransport() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context'.

Comment: Which CodeIgniter version are you using? Which PHP version are you using? There is an incompatibility with the way a variable is being handled.

Comment: i am using codeigniter 3.0 and php 5.6

Comment: I would try to change different php versions and see